# How are (landing) doors kept open in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, artificial-gravity

My question is a possible duplication but I am trying to be specific from this question "[How does gravity work on Star Wars ships?](http://%20How%20does%20gravity%20work%20on%20Star%20Wars%20ships?)"

My question is when space ships are docking into big stations like the Death Star, the doors/hanger are open how is this possible in space? They have open doors of the atmosphere and no one is forced out?

See picture for example

[image]

Comment: In one of the 'Legends' books, it was explained by a force field blocking the air flowing out.

Comment: Modern technology, William.

Comment: Does George Lucas write the fictional information about maps, diagrams and all information or is all fan based and fan generated over the years. Side note: @Valorum Thanks point dexter

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid - You see the shields in Revenge of the Sith.